# Why won't this insert into my database, using python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7

I am trying to insert some strings into my database.

```
import mysql.connector
import web

from mysql.connector import Error
import cgi, cgitb

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='adatabase', user='root', password='')
cursor = conn.cursor()

if conn.is_connected():
    print('Connected to MySQL database')



fullname = "fullname"
email ="email"
comments = "comments"
sql = """INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `comments`, `time`) VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, )""" % (fullname, email, comments)

cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()  
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

It gives me this error. Note, I have mysql-connector-python_1.2.3 installed when it gave me this error.

```
Connected to MySQL database
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "commentsscript.cgi", line 108, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 494, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 683, in cmd_query
    statement))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 601, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

and I've also gotten this error, when I didn't have mysql-connector-python installed and instead, mysqlworkbench

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "commentsscript.cgi", line 108, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 494, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 683, in cmd_query
    statement))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 601, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'fullname' in 'field list'
```

**Thing's I've tried**

Passing variables into a create table statement. This works.

```
anooog1 = "thing"
sql = """CREATE TABLE thiga (%s INT, COL2 INT )""" % (anooog1)
```

Also passing the strings directly. This is redundant kind of, considering that I want this to eventually pass variables from HTML. I've been testing the syntax.

```
sql = """INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `comments`, `time`) VALUES (NULL, "fullname", "email", "comments", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"""
```

(I am also having trouble getting cgi scripts to run in apache, but that's a different problem,this testing is being done on the terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Don't use string formatting to insert your variables into SQL queries* - this is, for the least, makes your code vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You are also missing the value for the `time` column in your query and I'm pretty sure you had to put your placeholders into quotes (`%s` -> `"%s"`).

Anyway, *parameterize your query*:

```
sql = """
    INSERT INTO 
        comments 
        (id, name, email, comments, time) 
    VALUES 
        (NULL, %s, %s, %s, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
"""
cursor.execute(sql, (fullname, email, comments))
```

Note that quotes around placeholders are not needed here - the database driver in this case handles the type conversions automatically.

Comment: I had current timestamp in there like a few minutes ago and was still getting the same errors. It works tho with this new syntax.